# Aggregate netCDF data to mean, min, max

Tags: python, dask, netcdf, python-xarray

I have several `netCDF` files which can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1c8EsGkgWcEkGG40TbncysPuJJGO3N2fG), created by [Coperinucs](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-land-monthly-means?tab=form). There are four files, each file is about 1GB.

I read the file like so

```
import xarray as xr

dset = xr.open_dataset("~/.../ERA5land1.nc")
```

Which gives me

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 61, longitude: 101, time: 87647)
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 31.0 30.9 30.8 30.7 ... 25.3 25.2 25.1 25.0
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 79.0 79.1 79.2 79.3 ... 88.7 88.8 88.9 89.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1981-01-01T01:00:00 ... 1990-12-31T23:00:00
Data variables:
    t2m        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<shape=(87647, 61, 101), chunksize=(10, 61, 101)>
Attributes:
    Conventions:  CF-1.6
    history:      2020-03-10 16:47:13 GMT by grib_to_netcdf-2.16.0: /opt/ecmw...
```

Calculating the mean should be straight forward according to the [documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.mean.html)

```
    mean = dset.mean()
```

That causes the computer to freeze and finally crash. Trying to `chunk` the data does not work neither.

```
    dset = xr.open_dataset("~/.../ERA5land1.nc", chunks = {'time': 10})
    mean = dset.mean()
```

That does not crash, but I get this

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  ()
Data variables:
     t2m      float32 dask.array<shape=(), chunksize=()>
```

I wonder how I can calculate the `min`, `max` and `mean` for each grid cell and store it in a new `netCDF` file with the same specs.

Comment: If you are attempting to get the mean for each grid cell, you need to specify the dimension to calculate over.  Try `mean = dset.mean(dim='time')` or `mean = dset['t2m'].mean(dim='time')`

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using my package nctoolkit (available through pip: https://pypi.org/project/nctoolkit/, user guide: https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html).

This uses CDO as a backend, so should be able to handle your data easily.

The code required would be very similar to what you have provided.

```
import nctoolkit as nc
dset = nc.open_data("~/.../ERA5land1.nc")
mean = dset.tmean()
```

If you then want an xarray array you would do this:

```
mean.to_xarray()
```